# In Grimrock, where do the dragons intersect to open the door? I opted not to use automap

Tags: legend-of-grimrock

I'm regretting the decision immensely to not start with automap.

Could anyone explain where they meet? I've googled a billion times but can't find a helpful answer, as it seems everyone else had the genius idea of embarking with automap.

Comment: I think the dragon ate SLC before he could finish writing that last "automap" :)

Comment: Hahaha oops how did I miss that? :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, you didn't use automap, but luckily the intersection point isn't far from the save crystal, so you should be able to use that as a point of reference on the map below.

- The save crystal is at the point labeled **A**
- The dragons are at the two points labeled **B**
- The circled area with the green arrows pointing to it is the intersection of the dragons' gaze.

[image]

So to get there from the save crystal:

1. Go find the save crystal which has a pit right next to it.
2. Head out the door (west) that's right by the crystal.
3. Turn left (south). Go that direction two steps so that you're bumping up against the wall.
4. Strafe one square right (west).
5. Move one more square forward (south). Rest here. It should trigger the opening of the iron door.

Now that I'm looking at it, another way of approaching this without automap is:

1. Go to the iron door. Turn around so that it's directly behind you.
2. Strafe one square right.
3. Run forward 6 squares until you run into the wall. Rest here.

Comment: Thanks this worked great! I wish I'd never started without the automap off.

Comment: @SLC. If you chose the oldschool option, you would have to get some square-lined paper and actually draw maps yourself, like we did back in the day (I did plenty of that, so I opted out, he-he).